# How to get the guests no in POS receipt in odoo

Tags: python-3.x, odoo

Please let me know if it is possible to get the guests no in odoo POS receipt when we take a print.

Thank you.

Comment: its already in pos_restaurant  module ,  <t t-if='receipt.customer_count'>
                <div>Guests: <t t-esc='receipt.customer_count' /></div>
            </t>

Comment: Do you know how to get a KOT no in pos receipt..?